# how to specify correct path to *.apk in docker-compose.yml and configure appium capabilities

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose, appium, selenium-grid

**Main goal:** run appium cases on mobile emulator which is in docker grid

So docker started and grid is running with needed mobile emulator

**Faced problem:** could not figure out how to start needed application on this emulator ?! =(

path where docker-compose.yml file located : */home/myComp/Documents/docker-appium*

Below is docker-compose.yml file:

```
.....
  # Docker-Android for Android application testing
  nexus_7.1.1:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-7.1.1
    privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    scale: 1
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
      - real_device
    ports:
      - 6080
    volumes:
      - /home/myComp/Documents/docker-appium/exmpl/sample_apk/app-to-test.apk
      - ./video-nexus_7.1.1:/tmp/video
    environment:
      - DEVICE=Nexus 5
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - AUTO_RECORD=true
.....
```

and code where capabilities setup:

```
extraCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/home/myComp/Documents/docker-appium/exmpl/sample_apk/app-to-test.apk");
```

but get ar error:

```
error: The application at '.....' does not exist or is not accessible
```

Could please someone explain how to set correct path to *.apk file in docker compose file and which path should be specified at capabilities class?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer was:**

-docker compose:

```
./example/sample_apk:/root/tmp
```

-capability class:

```
extraCapabilities.setCapability("app", "//root/tmp/app-to-test.apk");
```